# Pass Object Parameter from javascript\ajax to function in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a table that i want to be able to update the status of each line that checkbox is on
(see attached screenshot)[image]

The checkbox propery in the Model is Not Mapped to the database ([NotMapped])
Html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ApproveStatus()">Approve Checked Lines</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

javaScript:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ApproveStatus() {
            var pdata = new FormData();

            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "Once Updated, you will not be able to Undo this",
                icon: "warning",
                buttons: true,
                dangerMode: true,
            })
                .then((willDelete) => {
                    if (willDelete) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "PaymentHistory/ApproveStatus",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: pdata,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            success: function (data) {
                                swal("Success!", {
                                    icon: "success",
                                });
                            }
                        });
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            location.reload()
                        }, 100);
                    } else {
                        swal("Nothing Changed!");
                    }
                });
        }
    </script>
}
```

And in the Controller i have the function (haven't written the logic yet)

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ApproveStatus()
{
}
```

table in html:

```
<table id="tblData" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr class="table-info">
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Payment Type</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Payment Date</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th></th>
    </thead>
    @foreach (PaymentHistory paymentHistory in Model)
    {
        <tr>
   <td>@ViewBag.getPaymentAddress(paymentHistory.SentFromAddressId).ToString()</td>     <td>@ViewBag.getPaymentType(paymentHistory.SentFromAddressId).ToString()</td>
            <td>@paymentHistory.Amount$</td>
            <td>@paymentHistory.PayDate</td>
            <td>@paymentHistory.Status</td>
            @if (paymentHistory.Status != "Approved")
            {
                <td>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@paymentHistory.isChecked"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td></td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

My only issue is that i want to pass the Object from the View (that contains the lines and status of the checkbox) to the function in the controller as a parameter,
Any ideas how can i do this?
Thank you

Comment: Can you share how the html for the check boxes were put togather?

Comment: added to the post, thanks

Comment: That is my question, how to pass that array of id from javaxcript to Ajax and then to the controller :)

Comment: You can try to add a hidden filed for `SentFromAddressId`, so that you can get it for each checked row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to pass the Object from the View (that contains the lines and status of the checkbox) to the function in the controller as a parameter, Any ideas how can i do this?

To achieve your requirement, you can try to add a hidden field for `SentFromAddressId` field, like below.

```
<td>
    <div class="text-center">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@paymentHistory.SentFromAddressId" />
        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@paymentHistory.isChecked" />
    </div>
</td>
```

then you can get the `sentFromAddressId` of each checked row and populate it in form data object.

```
var pdata = new FormData();

$("input[name='paymentHistory.isChecked']:checked").each(function (index, el) {
    var sentFromAddressId = $(this).siblings("input[type='hidden']").val();
    pdata.append("Ids", sentFromAddressId);
})
```

and post the data to action method with following code snippet.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/PaymentHistory/ApproveStatus',
    data: pdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (res) {
        //...
    }
});
```

*ApproveStatus action method*

```
public IActionResult ApproveStatus(int[] Ids)
{
    //code logic here
    //update corresponding record based on id within Ids
```

Comment: Amazing,
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Get all checked checkboxes id in an array, use that array to update table